# SQL Server running on unknown user

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2017.

I face the following issue:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Server VMSERVER\SERVERNAME, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\temp\database.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server VMSERVER\SERVERNAME, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I did some search and most of the time, the usual recommendation is : make sure the destination folder has the permissions set right for the User under which the service SQL Server is running.

I checked the name user name of the said service and got `NT Service\MSSQL$SERVERNAME`

I can not find this user when I look into the Security section of the `C:\Temp` folder.

Is my only option to change the user under which the SQL Server service is running?

Comment: Specifically account is `NT Service\MSSQL$<Instance Name>`. So if your SQL Server instance is `VMSERVER\FOOBARBAZ` then the account will be `NT Service\MSSQL$FOOBARBAZ`. You won't find this account name in Local User Manager (lusrmgr.msc) or most user interfaces. That you can't see it on the Security tab for `C:\Temp` means that permissions have not been granted for it there. You should be able to add the account from the Security tab with Full Control, or from a Run-as-Administrator command prompt with something like: `icacls.exe C:\Temp /grant "NT Service\MSSQL$FOOBARBAZ":(F)`

Comment: I ended up allowing access to the folder to `Everyone` , I am well aware of the security risks but given that this server is not accessible from outside out 20ppl office, I feel good with that.